# Exe & Dll analyzer and decompiler

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, decompiling

can anyone please suggest me what software can i use for reverse engineering for decompiling exe and a dll file?

I need to understand as more information as i can on what these files do, in what language they are writen ext.

I am already trying with:
Olly Debug
ExeToC
Boomerang

Comment: [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this also DeDe , HDasm , Win32dasm

DeDe is a very fast program that can analyze executables compiled with Delphi

http://hdasm.narod.ru/

but IDA  is the best

Answer (score 5):

The interactive disassembler (IDA) from Hex-Rays ([www.hex-rays.com](http://www.hex-rays.com)) is a state of the art tool for the purpose of reverse engineering.

Comment: But its hella complicated!